# NoMethodError when modifying database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing a beginners exercise for rails. I am creating an app that creates a new article in the database. I have:

```rb
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `Article.string`, I get the following message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `title=' for #<Article:0x00007f8d5d4d6100>)
```

The app does not seem to recognise the methods `string` and `text`.
I am using ruby 2.5.3 . The tutorial uses 2.2 . Could this be the issue Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Do you have a `article` model?.

Comment: Yes, it is empty though.

Comment: ```class Article < ApplicationRecord
end````

Comment: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html  That is the task I am working on.

Comment: "When I run Article.string" - why? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: It should at least ouput nil, but it looks like, the column for title and body are no even defined (see below)

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
rails g model Article title:string body:text
```

But i think the problem is with the method `Article.string` you mentioned though. Could it be that you mean to do the `Article.all` instead to query all records from the articles table from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Run

`article = Article.new
 article.title => nil`

`article = Article.new
 article.title = 'Your name' 
 article.body = 'Some text'
 article.save`

Because title can be accessed by any instance of an Article using ORM.

Here string is an data type for your column title. Not an method

PS: Please run rake db:migrate if it gives migration error.

Comment: irb(main):001:0> Article.new 
=> #<Article id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> Article.title
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `title' for Article(id: in
teger, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime):Class)
irb(main):003:0> article = Article.new
=> #<Article id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> article.title => nil
Traceback (most recent call last):
SyntaxError ((irb):4: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecti
ng end-of-input)
article.title => nil
              ^~

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. For some reason downgrading the ruby version fixed the issue.